# csv filter function does not execute the columns that I want it to filter

Tags: python, csv

I want to make a code that filters the columns of a csv file,
However, it executes something else that is not, I do not know if the problem is in the function of opening csv or when I call the function flitrar.

Here I leave you step by step what my code does:

1. this is my function that reads the csv and converts it so that it can read

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple



Almacenamiento_de_datos = namedtuple('Almacenamiento_de_datos','Tipo_de_sangre,Nombres,Genero,Cuerpo,Distrito,'
                                                           'DENUNCIADO,Estatura,Edad,Cuando_Desparecio')


def abrir_csv (Doc):
    with open( Doc , encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lector = csv.reader(f)
        next(lector)
        contenido=[(Almacenamiento_de_datos(Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres, Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito, DENUNCIADO,
                                         float(Estatura),int(Edad),Cuando_Desparecio) for Tipo_de_sangre, Nombres,
                                                                                          Genero, Cuerpo, Distrito,
                                                                                          DENUNCIADO,Estatura, Edad,
                                                                                          Cuando_Desparecio in lector)]
        return contenido
```

2. this is my other function that calls csv to be filtered

```
def Filtrar_Contenido (Doc):
    contenido1 = {"{}".format(s.Nombres for s in Doc)}
    return contenido1
```

3. to call this function I had to create another function to iterate my csv file and create another function that prints the columns.

```
from Desaparecidos  import *  #which has the 2 functions of open file and filter


def Tetscontador(datos):
    for dato in datos:
        print(dato)

def TestFiltro_nombres(fichero):
    print(Tetscontador(Filtrar_Contenido(fichero)))
    print("Estos son los nombres y  de las personas desaparecidas")


Doc=abrir_csv('../data/DESAPARECIDOS_INDIA_2018_2020.csv')

TestFiltro_nombres(Doc)
```

but the console gives me this result:

```
<generator object Filtrar_Contenido.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000002157AAF5C80>
None
```

when to debug the file in the document location
(Doc = open_csv ('../ data / DISAPARECIDOS_INDIA_2018_2020.csv'))
I get the same thing that I get in the console, does that mean that the cs file is not opening?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aycje.png)

Comment: The code of "TestFiltro_nombres" is not shown in the question.

Comment: ready the testflitro_names function I already put it, it was my mistake when asking

Comment: In "Filtrar_Contenido" instead of `contenido1 = {"{}".format(s.Nombres for s in Doc)}` write `contenido1 = {"{}".format(s.Nombres) for s in Doc}` (only closing parenthesis moved). This should be at least nearer towards what you want.

Comment: new error : contenido1 = {"{}".format(s.Nombres) for s in Doc}
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'Nombres'

Comment: In "abrir_csv" you define "contenido" as a list with a single element which is a generator expression. Probably you want replace `contenido=[(...)]` by `contenido=[...]` (removing the outmost parentheses).